# Rails Rspec errors on Github actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github-actions

I keep getting errors with RSpec on Github Actions. Not sure what's going on.
I'm on Rails 7 and Ruby 3.

Locally Rspec runs fine. I'm new to Github actions and have been fumbling around with it for a few hours now. It seems like an environment issue where Rails isn't loaded correctly but I'm not sure where the problem could be. Does anyone have a working Github actions example with Rails 7, Ruby 3 and RSpec?

Here's my github actions config:

```
# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.  They are
# provided by a third-party and are governed by separate terms of service,
# privacy policy, and support documentation.
#
# This workflow will install a prebuilt Ruby version, install dependencies, and
# run tests and linters.
name: "Ruby on Rails CI"
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:14-alpine
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: starter_rails_api_test
          POSTGRES_USER: rails
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5

    env:
      RAILS_ENV: test
      DATABASE_URL: "postgres://rails:password@localhost:5432/starter_rails_api_test"
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # Add or replace dependency steps here
      - name: Install Ruby and gems
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          bundler: default
          # bundler-cache: true
      - name: Install gems
        run: bin/bundle install
      # Add or replace database setup steps here
      - name: Create database tables
        run: bin/rails db:create
      - name: Set up database schema
        run: bin/rails db:schema:load
      # Add or replace test runners here
      - name: Run tests
        run: bin/bundle exec rspec spec

  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Ruby and gems
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          bundler-cache: true
      # Add or replace any other lints here
      # - name: Security audit dependencies
      #   run: bin/bundler-audit --update
      # - name: Security audit application code
      #   run: bin/brakeman -q -w2
      - name: Lint Ruby files
        run: bin/bundle exec rubocop --parallel
```

Output:

```
Run bin/bundle exec rspec spec
  

An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/widget_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: rescue_from ActiveModel::ValidationError, with: ->(e) { handle_validation_error(e) }

NameError:
  uninitialized constant ActiveModel::ValidationError

    rescue_from ActiveModel::ValidationError, with: ->(e) { handle_validation_error(e) }
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Did you mean?  ActiveModel::Validator
# ./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21:in `<class:ApplicationController>'
# ./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:5:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/models/widget_spec.rb:3:in `require'
# ./spec/models/widget_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'

An error occurred while loading ./spec/requests/api/v1/widgets_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

FrozenError:
  can't modify frozen Array: ["/home/runner/work/starter-rails-api/starter-rails-api/app/controllers", "/home/runner/work/starter-rails-api/starter-rails-api/app/controllers/concerns", "/home/runner/work/starter-rails-api/starter-rails-api/app/lib", "/home/runner/work/starter-rails-api/starter-rails-api/app/models", "/home/runner/work/starter-rails-api/starter-rails-api/app/models/concerns", "/home/runner/work/starter-rails-api/starter-rails-api/app/serializers"]
# ./config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/requests/api/v1/widgets_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'

An error occurred while loading ./spec/routing/api/v1/widgets_routing_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

FrozenError:
  can't modify frozen Array: ["/home/runner/work/starter-rails-api/starter-rails-api/app/controllers", "/home/runner/work/starter-rails-api/starter-rails-api/app/controllers/concerns", "/home/runner/work/starter-rails-api/starter-rails-api/app/lib", "/home/runner/work/starter-rails-api/starter-rails-api/app/models", "/home/runner/work/starter-rails-api/starter-rails-api/app/models/concerns", "/home/runner/work/starter-rails-api/starter-rails-api/app/serializers"]
# ./config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/routing/api/v1/widgets_routing_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00006 seconds (files took 1.3 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 3 errors occurred outside of examples

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Fiddled around a lot with the github actions config. No luck. Always getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a Rails issue not Github actions. Weird that it only happens on linux and not on osx.

Fixed it by adding `require 'active_model/validations'` to my `application_controller.rb` file. Not sure why it's not already required automatically.

If anyone can shed some light on this I'd appreciate it.

For reference this is where the class is defined:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8015c2c2cf5c8718449677570f372ceb01318a32/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L425

Comment: Are you using different configurations for dev, test, and production environments? For example, eager loading? Gems such as spring? It's a common problem to have production configured differently from dev and test for speed and convenience, only to have everything break in production. Keep dev, test, and prod configs as similar as possible.

Comment: I am also having this issue, but I don't have `require "active_job/railtie"`. Should I be including it?